# File upload on persistent volume on Openshift 3 (SFTP, FTP, etc.)

Tags: openshift

Is there any way that I can upload files to my persistent volume? Client tools provides an ssh option but how about uploading multiple files using sftp?

Comment: There is a 3 part blog series about this going out at the moment. First part is https://blog.openshift.com/transferring-files-in-and-out-of-containers-in-openshift-part-1-manually-copying-files/ and second part https://blog.openshift.com/transferring-files-in-and-out-of-containers-in-openshift-part-2/ third part soon.

Comment: Using ``oc rsync`` is easiest way. Allowing ``sftp`` is more work as requires setting up a side car containers and then you still need port forwarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use `oc rsh`, see `oc rsh --help` to sync local directories with that of the containers. You can also use `oc rsync` or `oc cp` to copy files, at least in later versions of OpenShift.